# hyperjaxb3 not generating files

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, maven, hyperjaxb

I am trying to learn hyperjaxb by studying [this tutorial](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/HJ3/Purchase+Order+Tutorial).  I followed all of the instructions down to the heading section `What was Generated?`.  This included the following steps:

1. download the [Basic Project Template for Hibernate and Maven](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/HJ3/Downloads)
2. unzip the file
3. install the xml and xsd files in the assigned locations
4. open up `cmd.exe`
5. navigate to the directory of the unzipped root folder
6. run mvn clean install

But nothing was generated.  There is no `/generated-sources/xjc` directory, and there is no `PurchaseOrderType.java`.  I did a key word search of the entire directory structure to confirm that these resources were not present after running `mvn clean install`.  I also imported the directory structure into a new eclipse maven project and tried `run as...maven clean` and `run as...maven build` within the new Eclipse Maven project, but got the same lack of results.

What can I do to get this tutorial to produce the intended generated files?

Also, is there a better way to generate JPA entities from xsd?

### Edit

As per @kapep's advice, I tried `mvn generate-sources` and got the following results:

[image]

I then tried `mvn clean install` again, and got the following results:

[image]

You can see the warning in the print screens that `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin` is missing.  I found the corresponding folder in the `.m2` repository on my machine and deleted it, then did a `maven update project` from within eclipse to re-download the library.  I then did another `mvn clean install`, and got the same lack of results.  Nothing was generated, no java file, no `generated-sources` directory.  Nothing.

What else can I try?

### Second edit

The tutorial app still DOES NOT generate the intended files, however, I was able to get rid of the warning message in the print screens by changing the maven-compiler-plugin portion of the pom to the following:

```
<plugin>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Note that, in addition to specifying the version, I also changed the `source` and `target` from `1.5` to `1.6`, as per @Todd 's advice [in this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123044/maven-3-warnings-about-build-plugins-plugin-version).  I assume these refer to JDK versions.  My installation uses JDK 1.6.  I do not know if this is causing any problems.

What else can I try?

Comment: I never used this library but it looks like you could try to run `mvn generate-sources` directly.

Comment: @kapep Thank you.  I just posted a couple of print screens showing the results of trying your advice.

Comment: @CodeMed I'm currently moving Hyperjaxb3 to GitHub. When it's done I'll make sure the tutorial works. https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3

Comment: @lexicore Are you willing to help me with this related problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26267272/configuring-hyperjaxb-to-create-hibernate-mappings-and-a-mysql-database

Comment: Please post your `mvn clean install -X` log as well as `dir /b /s' log. (You can first redirect to a file like `mvn clean install -X > log`.)

Comment: @CodeMed Did you actually put `po.xsd` to the right place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Finally it appeared that the OP was looking for generated classes in the root directory of the project instead of `target\generated-source\xjc`, despite the [tutorial](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/HJ3/Purchase+Order+Tutorial) clearly states where to look:

> If you browse the target/generated-sources/xjc directory, you'll find
>   few generated java files, for instance `PurchaseOrderType.java`.

---

Once again, I don't get this. Works for me.

My steps are:

- Unzip [`hyperjaxb3-ejb-template-basic-0.6.0-maven-src.zip`](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/releases/download/0.6.0/hyperjaxb3-ejb-template-basic-0.6.0-maven-src.zip) into some location
- Put `schema.xsd` into `src/main/resources`
- Put `po.xml` into `src/test/samples`
- `mvn clean install`

And this is what I get, nice and clean:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3:hyperjaxb3-ejb-template-basic-maven:jar:0.6.0
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 75, column 12
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Hyperjaxb3 Samples [po-initial:maven] 0.6.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ hyperjaxb3-ejb-template-basic-maven ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Projects\workspaces\hj3\dist\hyperjaxb3-ejb-template-basic-0.6.0\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-hyperjaxb3-plugin:0.6.0:generate (default) @ hyperjaxb3-ejb-template-basic-maven ---
[INFO] Sources are not up-to-date; XJC execution will be executed.
[WARNING] According to the Java Persistence API specification, section 2.1, entities must be top-level classes:
"The entity class must be a top-level class."
Your JAXB model is not customized as with top-level local scoping, please use the <jaxb:globalBinding localScoping="toplevel"/> global bindings customization.
        org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3.ejb.plugin.EjbPlugin

[WARNING] According to the Java Persistence API specification, section 2.1, entities must implement the serializable interface:
"If an entity instance is to be passed by value as a detached object
(e.g., through a remote interface), the entity class must implement
 the Serializable interface."
Your JAXB model is not customized as serializable, please use the <jaxb:serializable/> global bindings customization element to make your model serializable.
        org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3.ejb.plugin.EjbPlugin

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ hyperjaxb3-ejb-template-basic-maven ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ hyperjaxb3-ejb-template-basic-maven ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 5 source files to C:\Projects\workspaces\hj3\dist\hyperjaxb3-ejb-template-basic-0.6.0\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ hyperjaxb3-ejb-template-basic-maven ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ hyperjaxb3-ejb-template-basic-maven ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 5 source files to C:\Projects\workspaces\hj3\dist\hyperjaxb3-ejb-template-basic-0.6.0\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ hyperjaxb3-ejb-template-basic-maven ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Projects\workspaces\hj3\dist\hyperjaxb3-ejb-template-basic-0.6.0\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running RoundtripTest
Detected [file:/C:/Projects/workspaces/hj3/dist/hyperjaxb3-ejb-template-basic-0.6.0/target/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml].
    RoundtripTest

Loading entity manager factory properties.
    RoundtripTest

Loading entity manager factory properties from [file:/C:/Projects/workspaces/hj3/dist/hyperjaxb3-ejb-template-basic-0.6.0/target/test-classes/persistence.properties].
    RoundtripTest

Testing samples.
    RoundtripTest

Sample directory [C:\Projects\workspaces\hj3\dist\hyperjaxb3-ejb-template-basic-0.6.0\src\test\samples].
    RoundtripTest

Testing sample [po.xml].
    RoundtripTest

Unmarshalling.
    RoundtripTest

Opening session.
    RoundtripTest

Saving the object.
    RoundtripTest

Opening session.
    RoundtripTest

Loading the object.
    RoundtripTest

Closing the session.
    RoundtripTest

Initial object:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<purchaseOrder orderDate="1999-10-20">
    <shipTo country="US">
        <name>Alice Smith</name>
        <street>123 Maple Street</street>
        <city>Mill Valley</city>
        <state>CA</state>
        <zip>90952</zip>
    </shipTo>
    <billTo country="US">
        <name>Robert Smith</name>
        <street>8 Oak Avenue</street>
        <city>Old Town</city>
        <state>PA</state>
        <zip>95819</zip>
    </billTo>
    <comment>Hurry, my lawn is going wild!</comment>
    <items>
        <item partNum="872-AA">
            <productName>Lawnmower</productName>
            <quantity>1</quantity>
            <USPrice>148.95</USPrice>
            <comment>Confirm this is electric</comment>
        </item>
        <item partNum="926-AA">
            <productName>Baby Monitor</productName>
            <quantity>1</quantity>
            <USPrice>39.98</USPrice>
            <shipDate>1999-05-21</shipDate>
        </item>
    </items>
</purchaseOrder>

    RoundtripTest

Source object:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<purchaseOrder orderDate="1999-10-20" Hjid="1">
    <shipTo country="US" Hjid="2">
        <name>Alice Smith</name>
        <street>123 Maple Street</street>
        <city>Mill Valley</city>
        <state>CA</state>
        <zip>90952</zip>
    </shipTo>
    <billTo country="US" Hjid="1">
        <name>Robert Smith</name>
        <street>8 Oak Avenue</street>
        <city>Old Town</city>
        <state>PA</state>
        <zip>95819</zip>
    </billTo>
    <comment>Hurry, my lawn is going wild!</comment>
    <items Hjid="1">
        <item partNum="872-AA" Hjid="1">
            <productName>Lawnmower</productName>
            <quantity>1</quantity>
            <USPrice>148.95</USPrice>
            <comment>Confirm this is electric</comment>
        </item>
        <item partNum="926-AA" Hjid="2">
            <productName>Baby Monitor</productName>
            <quantity>1</quantity>
            <USPrice>39.98</USPrice>
            <shipDate>1999-05-21</shipDate>
        </item>
    </items>
</purchaseOrder>

    RoundtripTest

Result object:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<purchaseOrder orderDate="1999-10-20" Hjid="1">
    <shipTo country="US" Hjid="2">
        <name>Alice Smith</name>
        <street>123 Maple Street</street>
        <city>Mill Valley</city>
        <state>CA</state>
        <zip>90952</zip>
    </shipTo>
    <billTo country="US" Hjid="1">
        <name>Robert Smith</name>
        <street>8 Oak Avenue</street>
        <city>Old Town</city>
        <state>PA</state>
        <zip>95819</zip>
    </billTo>
    <comment>Hurry, my lawn is going wild!</comment>
    <items Hjid="1">
        <item partNum="872-AA" Hjid="1">
            <productName>Lawnmower</productName>
            <quantity>1</quantity>
            <USPrice>148.95</USPrice>
            <comment>Confirm this is electric</comment>
        </item>
        <item partNum="926-AA" Hjid="2">
            <productName>Baby Monitor</productName>
            <quantity>1</quantity>
            <USPrice>39.98</USPrice>
            <shipDate>1999-05-21</shipDate>
        </item>
    </items>
</purchaseOrder>

    RoundtripTest

Checking the document identity.
    RoundtripTest

Finished testing sample [po.xml].
    RoundtripTest

Finished testing samples.
    RoundtripTest

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.456 sec

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ hyperjaxb3-ejb-template-basic-maven ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Projects\workspaces\hj3\dist\hyperjaxb3-ejb-template-basic-0.6.0\target\hyperjaxb3-ejb-template-basic-maven-0.6.0.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ hyperjaxb3-ejb-template-basic-maven ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Projects\workspaces\hj3\dist\hyperjaxb3-ejb-template-basic-0.6.0\target\hyperjaxb3-ejb-template-basic-maven-0.6.0.jar to C:\Repository\org\jvnet\hyperjaxb3\hyperjaxb3-ejb-template-basic-maven\0.6.0\hyperjaxb3-ejb-template-basic-maven-0.6.0.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Projects\workspaces\hj3\dist\hyperjaxb3-ejb-template-basic-0.6.0\pom.xml to C:\Repository\org\jvnet\hyperjaxb3\hyperjaxb3-ejb-template-basic-maven\0.6.0\hyperjaxb3-ejb-template-basic-maven-0.6.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.185 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-10-09T00:56:18+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/101M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have no idea why it does not work for you. Pleas post `mvn clean install -X` and `dir /b/s` logs so that I could check your setup.