# no persistence provider for EntityManager named persistence.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa, hyperjaxb

**This is not a duplicate as the tag above purports.  This question has not yet been answered.**

I am trying to set up [this tutorial](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/HJ3/Purchase+Order+Tutorial) to get `hyperjaxb` to work in an eclipse project.  How can I get it to see a persistence provider?  `hbm2ddl` has NOT created the table structure in the database yet.  Is that why the app is not seeing a persistence provider?  Or is it because the contents of `persistence.xml` in `target/generated-sources` are not accessible from the `src/main/java` directory in which my `TestFunctions.java` is trying to call it?  Here are the specifics... This line of code:

```
entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistence.xml", persistenceProperties);
```

Is throwing this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named persistence.xml
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at maintest.TestFunctions.setUpPersistence(TestFunctions.java:119)
    at maintest.Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

The code throwing the error is in this method:

```
public void setUpPersistence(){
    final Properties persistenceProperties = new Properties();
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        Class<? extends TestFunctions> c = getClass();
        ClassLoader cl = c.getClassLoader();
        is = cl.getResourceAsStream("persistence.properties");
        persistenceProperties.load(is);
    }catch (IOException i) {i.printStackTrace();}
    finally {if (is != null) {try {is.close();} catch (IOException ignored) {}}}
    entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistence.xml", persistenceProperties);
}
```

`persistence.xml`:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_1_0.xsd" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:orm="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <persistence-unit name="org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3.ejb.tests.po">
            <class>org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3.ejb.tests.po.Items</class>
            <class>org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3.ejb.tests.po.Items$Item</class>
            <class>org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3.ejb.tests.po.PurchaseOrderType</class>
            <class>org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3.ejb.tests.po.USAddress</class>
        </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

`persistence.properties` is:

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.connection.username=someusername
hibernate.connection.password=somepassword
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/somedatabasename
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=0
```

The directory structure for the eclipse project is:

[image]

---

### **EDIT:  **

Just for kicks, I moved the `META-INF` folder to the same level as the calling class, but I get the same error.  Here are two new screen shots showing locations of persistence.xml in which the error is still thrown:

[image]
[image]

---

### **SECOND EDIT:**

I added `Class c = Class.forName("org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider");` at line 116 of `TestFunctions.java`, which triggers the following error when I right click on `Main.java` and do `Run As..Java Application`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at maintest.TestFunctions.setUpPersistence(TestFunctions.java:116)
    at maintest.Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

Here is the new `TestFunctions.setUpPersistence()` method:

```
public void setUpPersistence() throws ClassNotFoundException{
    final Properties persistenceProperties = new Properties();
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        Class<? extends TestFunctions> c = getClass();
        ClassLoader cl = c.getClassLoader();
        is = cl.getResourceAsStream("persistence.properties");
        persistenceProperties.load(is);
    }catch (IOException i) {i.printStackTrace();}
    finally {if (is != null) {try {is.close();} catch (IOException ignored) {}}}//org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3.ejb.tests.po
    Class c = Class.forName("org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider");
    entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(/*"org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3.ejb.tests.po"*//*"persistence.xml"*/"org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3.ejb.tests.po", persistenceProperties);
}
```

When I replace `Class c = Class.forName("org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider");` with `Class c = Class.forName("org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence");`, I get a similar error.  However, `Class c = Class.forName("javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider");` does not throw any error, so the program continues until the same `javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3.ejb.tests.po` error gets thrown further downstream.

**Does this tell us more about the cause of the error?**  Also, `hyperjaxb` creates a `persistence.xml` and places it in the target folder.  This error occurred when `persistence.xml` was in that location, and has persisted when I move `persistence.xml` as shown above. **Is `hyperjaxb` causing this problem by not playing nicely with eclipse?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [No Persistence provider for EntityManager named X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322827/no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager-named-x)

Comment: @lexicore This is not a duplicate because I tried every answer in the other question, and still get the error.  I am looking for a deeper explanation.  The only thing from the other posting I have not tried is `Class c = Class.forName("org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider");`.  Where would I place that?

Comment: @lexicore Is this caused by a clash between `hyperjaxb` and eclipse?  Please see my second edit above.

Comment: The tutorial uses Hibernate als JPA provider, you're trying to instantiate EclipseLink.

Comment: @lexicore Thank you! I did figure that out. (See my second edit above.) At the moment, I am starting through the steps in your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just can't resist, this is my final attempt to help. :) I'm writing this for you and for any users who may encounter similar issues.

I believe you simply have a problem in the Eclipse project configuration. The paths in your Eclipse project do not seem correct.

Normally, when you import an existing Maven project into Eclipse using `File > Import... > Existing Maven Projects`, `m2eclipse` should analyse the structure of the Maven project and create Eclipse project with (`.classpath` and `.project` files) automatically.

The paths in these projects are derived from your Eclipse `pom.xml`. So you actually should not create/modify/add/remove/copy/move/whatever Eclipse source folders. If you do this, your Eclipse project will no longer be synchronized with your Maven project and you'll get really weird results.

Sometimes `m2eclipse` does not do its job well. Sometimes you don't get the right source folders, things go missing etc. From my experience, this got radically better over the time and right now `m2eclipse` works like a charm. From what I saw in your struggles, it might be that you have an older version of `m2eclipse`. Maybe not, but I'd suggest to check it anyway.

Next, sometimes `m2eclispe` still clamps. In this cases it is highly recommended to do the following things:

- Clean the project: `Project > Clean...`
- Update the Maven project (Alt + F5). Make sure to update the project configuration from `pom.xml`

[image]

Finally you should get the following project structure:

[image]

Specifically, you should get the following source folders:

- `src\main\java` - source folder for your main Java files
- `src\main\resources` - source folder for resources
- `target\generated-sources\xjc` - source folder for the generated code.

  - **Important:** not `target\generated-sources` like you have but `target\generated-sources\xjc`.
  - This folder contains the generated Java classes. (Hyperjaxb adds JPA annotations to them).
  - It also contains `META-INF\persistence.xml` which is a persistence unit descriptor. The `META-INF\persistence.xml` resource is specified by the JPA spec. This is where the persistence unit will be loaded from.
  - If you've generated a roundtrip test (xml-to-the-db-and-back), then you'll also see a `RoundtripTest` class somewhere. This is a JUnit test class, it should be possible to execute it directly. (`Run As > JUnit Test`)
- `src\test\java` - test classes.
- `src\test\resources` - test resources

This is a standard directory layout for Maven projects. The only peculiarity is the `target\generated-sources\xjc` source folder which holds the code generated by the schema compiler. And even this is absolutely standard, it is a usual convention for Maven code-generation plugins to generate code in `target\generated-sources\some-tool` directories.

Below I post the `.classpath` file from my project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry including="**/*.java" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="target/generated-sources/xjc">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/J2SE-1.5">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

**Important**

If you don't have this directory structure (and your screenshots show that you don't) **DO NOT** move on. It will fail (it does for you). Fix your project structure first. Do not move on, don't try to run anything, you'll run into all kinds of strange things like not found resources etc. (which you do).

Regenerate project structure from `pom.xml` and clean the project in Eclipse. Open your `.classpath` file and compare it line-by-line with what I posted. But please do fix the project structure first.

Next, it is important that you understand that you are not supposed to move or drag-and-drop the generated code. It is not the right thing to do.  Don't do it. **Please don't move on until you accept this as an imperative.** Don't move or modify the generated code. If you do, you overtake the responsibility for this code. Things are generated the way they are because it works this way. So if you change it it is very likely that it won't work anymore (it does not for you). If you will need to change anything, you change the `pom.xml` which configures the generation, not the resulting code.

Now, let us analyse your current project structure based on the following screenshot:

[image]

What I can notice:

- `src\main\java` contains `maintest\Main` and `TestFunctions`. If you're trying to write a test, put your test classes into `src\test\java`, not `src\main\java`.
- `src\main\resources` contains `persistence.xml`, `sun-jaxb.episode`, `persistence.properties` and `schema.xsd`. Only `schema.xsd` should be there.

  - `persistence.xml` and `sun-jaxb.episode` are generated files. And, see above, you must not move them.
  - `persistence.properties` defines the connection to the database used for testing. So it must be in test resources, namely `src\test\resources`. Putting it into `src\main\resources` will finally add this file into the resulting JAR, it's like telling everyone username and password of the database you use for testing
- `src\test\java` - this is OK, but your test classes should be here.
- `src\test\resources` - `persistence.properties` should be here.
- `target\generated-sources` - this is wrong, this should be `target\generated-sources\xjc`

  - `org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3.ejb.test.po` package is under `target\generated-sources`. It is *generated* under `target\generated-sources\xjc`, so what I see means you've moved. Don't do this, see above.
  - `xjc` is displayed as package. This is actually a leftover after you've (incorrectly) configured `target\generated-sources` as a source folder. This folder must contain all of the generated sources, now it only contains the `RoundtripTest`. Which means you moved the generated code. Don't do this, see the imperative above.

So your Eclipse project configuration as displayed above is invalid. Here's my theory on why this happened. I think that your `m2eclipse` did not process the `pom.xml` correctly, you were probably missing folders etc. But instead of getting the Eclipse project files to be correctly generated my `m2eclipse` you have manually added the `target\generated-sources` and started moving the generated code around. This is not the right way.

Please check and re-check your `.classpath` until it is equivalent to what I posted. I have zipped and [uploaded](https://jumpshare.com/v/tAJd33crHPnUKuuIYuyM?b=EEZa1wSOu7uQua3Fi3dU) my sample project which definitely works for me. You can unzip and import it using `File > Import... > Existing Projects into Eclipse` (not as Maven project).

Finally, you must be able to execute the `RoundtripTest` as a JUnit test. The test will probably fail, but it must run, you should not be getting NPEs etc. I don't have a MySQL database at hand, so this is what I get at the moment:

```
Detected [file:/C:/Projects/workspaces/hj3/hyperjaxb3-ejb-template-basic-0.6.0/target/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml].
    RoundtripTest

Loading entity manager factory properties.
    RoundtripTest

Loading entity manager factory properties from [file:/C:/Projects/workspaces/hj3/hyperjaxb3-ejb-template-basic-0.6.0/target/test-classes/persistence.properties].
    RoundtripTest

Could not obtain connection to query metadata
    org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory

com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.net.ConnectException
MESSAGE: Connection refused: connect
```

This means that entity manager started correctly but could not connect to the database. If you've configured your test database in the `src\test\resources\persistence.properties` corretcly, you should be able to connect to the database. And if you'll put a `po.xml` file to `src\test\samples`, the roundtrip test will:

- unmarshal this files
- save it into the database
- load it back
- compare it to the original result

Please get the roundrip test run first before you start your own experiments. Don't copy the code, don't modify it, don't try to bend it to your directory structure. It must run as it is. Don't move on until it does.

Good luck.

**Update.**

You might also be facing an issue with unresolved dependencies. Please make sure your dependencies are resolved correctly. This is what I see:

[image]

If you don't see this, it is bad. Something is wrong with your workspace. Check if you have any error messages in Eclipse. Maybe you have something like:

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:hibernate3-maven-plugin
```

Quick-fix it first ("Permanently mark goal ... as ignored in Eclispe build"). Don't move on until this error is gone. This is a blocker.

Comment: I want to re-import the project from scratch to reproduce your steps. Note that your project name is `hyperjaxb3-ejb-template-basic-0.6.0` and mine is `hyperjaxb3-ejb-samples-po-initial-maven`. Is that part of our problem communicating? I can only find `version 0.5.6` at your web site.

Comment: https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/releases but this should not make any difference as the projects are almost identical.

Comment: +1. I need to spend time with this tomorrow to check everything & assess the situation. For now, it seems to be creating the tables in the MySQL database, inserting data into & retrieving data from the database. My eclipse project has a slightly different structure than yours, but the `classpath` file is the same. It has not generated the `ddl`, though I imagine I can find a way to generate that from `hbm2ddl` or MySQL. When I finally get everything checked and tested, let's you & I collaborate to cleanup all these postings so other users can benefit, & so that neither you nor I feels beat up.

Comment: +1 for the effort. I think this should help solving the problem.

Comment: After studying the installed code, I have one comment and one question: `Comment:` I had to disable a JPA compile error in eclipse using `Properties-->Java Compiler-->Errors/Warnings`.  `Question:` Where do I put production code that needs to work with the generated classes? `Main.java/TestFunctions.java` work when located in `src/test/java` but fail after being moved to `src/main/java`.

Comment: Please ask two further separate questions, it's ok. JPA - would be good to know the error (JPA can't be _compile_ error). Prod code - ask it. We're overblowing the comments. :)

Comment: ok. I will save those questions to ask later.  I saved a backup of the working eclipse project and used a copy to test swapping out the xsd and xml files with real files I have tested in jaxb.  I would like to debug them myself, but I am getting nebulous error messages.  I posted that as a separate question at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26391467/importing-new-schema-into-hyperjaxb

Comment: @lexicore the thing that might be relevant still to this question is that following your instructions above explicitly created a `...po` package instead of a `...pocustomized` package, so I had to change the line in the pom.xml that contains `pocustomized` to `po` when running `mvn clean install` in the question linked in my preceding comment.  If this does not matter, then we can ignore it and move on.  I really do not care unless it creates other problems further down the line.

Comment: @CodeMed It is important that you use exactly the same persistence unit name in `RoundtripTest.getPersistenceUnitName()`, `persistence.xml`, must be also the name of the package where the classes are generated (see `bindings.xjb`).

Comment: @lexicore The persistence unit name in both the generated `persistence.xml` and the generated `RoundtripTest.getPersistenceUnitName()` are both `org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3.ejb.tests.po` instead of `org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3.ejb.tests.pocustomized` from the `pom.xml`, so `RoundtripTest,java` and `persistence.xml` at least match each other even if they are different than the `pom`.  There was no `bindings.xjb` generated when I explicitly followed all your steps above.

Comment: @lexicore I just downloaded your zip file above.  Let me make a copy of it, then swap out the `xsd` and `xml` files before doing `mvn clean install` on its root folder.  This will help determine whether we should focus on my other question or on why my system gave me a slightly different structure from your same explicit instructions.

Comment: @CodeMed Ok, then it's good. Just update the `pom.xml` then. I think you mean the `jpaconfiguration` line in `hbm2ddl`, right? The `persistenceunit` there should have the same name as everywhere else. For `bindings.xjb` check `src\main\resources`. It is not generated, it is manually written. Maybe you don't have that in your sample. I think I use this one: https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/blob/master/ejb/tests/po-customized/src/main/resources/bindings.xjb This file basically customizes the generation.

Answer (score 2):

The parameter you should pass is the **persistence-unit**. (Not the file name.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence version="1.0" ... >
    <persistence-unit name="generated">
        <class>generated.Items</class>
        <class>generated.Items$Item</class>
        <class>generated.PurchaseOrderType</class>
        <class>generated.USAddress</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

So it should be `generated` for the `persistence.xml` above:

```
entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("generated", persistenceProperties);
```

For your persistence, should be:

```
entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3.ejb.tests.po", persistenceProperties);
```

Comment: I now have `entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3.ejb.tests.po", persistenceProperties);` and kept `<persistence-unit name="org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3.ejb.tests.po">` in `persistence.xml` but the error is now `No Persistence provider for EntityManager named org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3.ejb.tests.po`.  Did I do what you suggest?

Comment: @CodeMed Can you double-check the persistence.xml is actually in the JAR and at the proper location?

Comment: @Puce Which JAR? persistence.xml is indeed in the eclipse directory structure.  I have not created any JARs, and I would not know which imported JAR if any to look in.

Comment: Take a look at the solution provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322827/no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager-named-x/19327322#19327322

Comment: @cmd Please see in my edit above the printscreens that show the `src\main\java\META-INF\persistence.xml` location suggested in your link.  The same error is still being thrown when I run Main.java with `persistence.xml` in the new location.  What else could be causing this problem?

Comment: @edubriguenti I added more information after trying different variations of `Class.forName()` at the end of my posting above.

Comment: @CodeMed You have a Maven project (pom.xml). Please runt "mvn clean install" and inspect the generated JAR in the target directory. Double-check that the persistence.xml file is in the correct location and the content of the persistence.xml is as you want it.